# Serverless AWS Lambda CORS Issue

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I am using `serverless` to deploy a lambda function that grabs a pdf of a website using puppeteer. This works well using Postman, but when I put in my code on a locally run Gatsby site I get a cors error...

`...from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

This is my yaml

```
    handler: pdf.index
    timeout: 30
    memorySize: 2048
    events:
      - http:
          method: GET
          path: /pdf
          contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
          cors: true 
    layers:
      - { Ref: ChromeLambdaLayer }
```

And this is my code in the handler...

```
   return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: pdf.toString("base64"),
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
        "Content-type": "application/pdf",
        "content-disposition": `attachment; filename=${name}.pdf`,
      },
      isBase64Encoded: true
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500
    };
  }
}
```

I have tried lots of options but none seem to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean in the Yaml?  I have tried that in the function as you can see from above. When I try * without quotes it does not work

Comment: Yes I tried the extension and it does work. But obviously that is not the answer for production

Comment: Thanks gosalia. Sorry again do you mean in the YAML? as I am already using 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'= '*' in the handler code

Answer (score 0):

You have to deal with the CORS within your handler itself. Which mean that you need to respond to the preflight request (OPTIONS).

```
function main(event, context, lambdaCallback) {
    if (event.httpMethod === 'OPTIONS') { // <-- Here
        doneOptions(200, '{"status": "OK"}', 'application/json', lambdaCallback);
    } else if (event.httpMethod === 'POST') { // <-- your actual functionality
        return fileRoute(event, context, lambdaCallback);
    } else {
        return done(400, '{"message":"Invalid HTTP Method"}', 'application/json', lambdaCallback);
    }
}

function doneOptions(statusCode, body, contentType, lambdaCallback, isBase64Encoded = false) {
    lambdaCallback(null, {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        isBase64Encoded: isBase64Encoded,
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization,Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Method': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS',
        }
    });
}
```